# 3 точки в Perl

Tags: perl

Добрый день.

Вот у меня какой вопрос. Существует оператор создания массива "..", т.е. например

```
@a = (1..3)
```

Но так же существует оператор "...", т.е например

```
@a = (1...3)
```

результат которого такой же, как и в предыдущем примере. Я читал документацию и англоязычную и русскоязычную - но все как-то размыто. Могли бы вы мне привести пример кода с использованием "...", выдающий результат, который я не смог бы реализовать при помощи ".."

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В своё время я в лекции рассказывал как они работают
https://youtu.be/2kq50cM6TDI?t=5478
Там показывается как посмотреть на поведение в скалярном контексте (при помощи `do { }`)

Comment: О, Владимир, приветсвую! Всегда мечтал поздороваться с вами на руСО)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разница в вычислении правого операнда.
В [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) есть отличный пример:

```
@lines = ("   - Foo",
          "01 - Bar",
          "1  - Baz",
          "   - Quux");

foreach (@lines) {
    if (/0/ .. /1/) {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Если использовать две точки, то вывод будет:

```
 01 - Bar
```

Если три точки, то:

```
 01 - Bar
 1  - Baz
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучший пример -- обработка файла "от сих до сих". Что-то вроде

```
while (<>) {
    if (/^BEGIN$/.../^END$/) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Работает в принципе как [триггер](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80). По дефолту выдаём `False`, как только первое условие становится `True`, запоминаем `True` и выдаем его, пока второе условие не станет `True`. Как только стало, запоминаем `False` и выдаем его пока первый параметр не станет `True` и т.д.

Comment: вот это уже интересней - пасибо

Answer (score 1):

Операторы `..` и `...` в списочном контексте не различаются, поэтому использование `...` для создания списка не имеет смысла.

А вот в скалярном контексте операторы различаются, но не на много. Оба оператора имеют внутреннюю память, в которой хранят своё состояние. И результат применения оператора зависит не только от текущих операндов, но и от состояния оператора. Переходы между состояниями описаны в [`perlop`](http://metacpan.org/module/perlop).

Comment: Да - да... все именно так в camelbook и написано. Но суть вопроса в привидении примера.

Answer (score -2):

А нет такого оператора ...
На самом деле все куда проще. Смотрим код (пользуемся тем, что между аргументом и оператором можно вставить пробел):

```
1..3 - это просто 123
1 .. 3 - смысл тот же, просто пробелов добавили
1 . . 3 - упс, а тут ошибка, хотя логично
1...3 - работает, смысл неизвестный
1 . .. 3 - не работает
1. .. 3 - работает
1. .. 3. - работает
```

Если ещё не понятно, то 1...3 - это 1. .. 3 - то есть 1.0 .. 3 - то есть, первая точка - это просто десятичная запятая и 1. преобразуется в 1
В строке "1. .. 3." как раз и понятно, что 1 и 3 тут просто записаны немного в непривычной форме.
Также попробуйте помедитировать на таким:

```
1.. .3
```

и почему print 1.. .3 выводит пустоту.

Comment: Кемелбук (стр. 141) - книга на русском.

Или "http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators"

If you don't want it to test the right operand until the next evaluation, as in sed, just use three dots ("...") instead of two. In all other regards, "..." behaves just like ".." does.

Еще есть знатоки?